# Why are Highly Rated Answers Below Bad Ones (Not including Correct)?

Tags: discussion

Have a look at this post:

[Multidimensional Array [][] vs [,]](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12567329/multidimensional-array-vs)

The fourth answer has over 150 upvotes, but its below numbers two and three, which only have about 5 stars each.

It makes sense that the correct answer, with a 190 upvotes, be number 1, but why should the fourth answer be in that position? It's easy to miss there, and clearly the upvotes indicate it has some valuable information.

Comment: Do you have it sorted by votes?

Answer (score 3):

Sort it by votes if you want it like that.

[image]